# airflow not downloading data

Tags: python, airflow

i'm trying to write a code to download sample data using airflow, the code seems to be correct it runs successfully but it doesnt download anything.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import requests
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import json
import time




def get_api():
    api_key = 'JJ2EJSN9PTN2RRNL'
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=IBM&apikey='+api_key
    r = requests.get(url)
    
    try: 
        data = r.json()
        path = 'C:/Users/HP/Documents/DATA_CENTER/data_lake/'
        with open(path + "stock_market_raw_data" + "IBM_" +  str(time.time()), "w") as outfile:
             json.dump(data, outfile)
    except:
         pass


default_dag_args= {
    'start_date': datetime(2023,1,1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email-on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay':timedelta(minutes=2),
    'project_id':1
}

with DAG('market_data_alpha_vantage',schedule_interval = '@daily', catchup =False,default_args=default_dag_args) as python_dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(task_id='get_market_data',python_callable = get_api)
```

it is supposed to download data into the specified path but it doesnt do anything

Comment: how do you run airflow ? self-mode or docker ? does your airflow process have permissions to "C:/Users/HP/Documents/DATA_CENTER/data_lake/" ? add a print in the except to see if you have any error.